# Prove that $f (x)$ = $g (x)$ + $ce ^ {x ^ 2}$

Tags: calculus

Let $g: [0,1]\to\Bbb R$ be a differentiable function. Show that if $f: [0,1]\to\Bbb R$ is a continuous function and satisfy the equation

$$f(x)= g(x) + \int_{0}^{x^2} f(\sqrt t) dt - \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2x} (t)g\left(\frac{t}{2}\right) dt$$

then there is a $c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f (x) = g (x) + ce ^ {x ^ 2}$

The first thing I did was to derive,can you help me?

Comment: If we put $x = 0$ in the relation given, we see that $f(0) = g(0)$. Then, if $f$ and $g$ satisfied the last equation you gave, wouldn't we have that $c = 0$?

Comment: Of course, then what I would have to prove is that  $f(x)-g(x)=0$?

Comment: Indeed but I think you can easily see that that is *not* true for an arbitrary continuous function $f$.

Comment: You can't prove it, because it's not true (just try with $g(x)=0$)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the given equation itself, if you make the substitutions $u = \sqrt t$ and $u = \frac{t}{2}$ respectively, you get

$$f(x) = g(x) + \int_0^x2uf(u)du -\frac{1}{2}\int_0^x2u\cdot g(u)\cdot(2du)$$

$$f(x) = g(x) + 2\int_0^xu\cdot[f(u)-g(u)]du$$

Let $h(x) = f(x)-g(x)$

Hence

$$h(x) = 2\int_0^xu\cdot h(u)du$$

$$\implies h'(x) = 2xh(x) $$

Hence $h(x) = ce^{x^2}$

Answer (score 0):

First take the derivative of both sides with respect to $x$:
$$f'(x)=g(x)+f(x)-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\int_{0}^{2x}t\cdot g\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)\mathrm{d}t$$
To make things a bit easier we make the substitution $u=\frac{t}{2}$, thus $\mathrm{d}t=2\mathrm{d}u$ and changing our limits of integration. $t=0 \implies u=0$ and $t=2x \implies u=x$ so
$$f'(x)=g(x)+f(x)-2\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\int_{0}^{x}u\cdot g\left(u\right)\mathrm{d}u$$
We now integrate by parts. Let $G$ be the antiderivative of $g$ and let $\mu=u$, $\mathrm{d}\mu=\mathrm{d}u$, $\mathrm{d\nu}=g(u)\mathrm{d}u$, $\nu=G(u)$. We know that
$$\int \mu \mathrm{d}\nu=\mu\nu-\int\nu\mathrm{d}\mu$$
changing our limits of integration. $t=0 \implies u=0$ and $t=2x \implies u=x$ thus
$$\int_{0}^{x}u\cdot g(u)\mathrm{d}u=u\cdot G(u)\bigg|_0^x-\int_{0}^{x}G(u)\mathrm{d}u=x\cdot G(x)-\int_{0}^{x}G(u)\mathrm{d}u$$
Then returning to the above,
$$f'(x)=g(x)+f(x)-2\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(x\cdot G(x)-\int_{0}^{x}G(u)\mathrm{d}u\right)$$
Using both the product rule and FTC,
$$f'(x)=g(x)+f(x)-2(G(x)+x\cdot g(x)-G(x))$$
Reducing and rearranging,
$$f'(x)-f(x)=(1-2x)g(x)$$
This is a first order linear differential equation, so the solution is found via [integrating factors](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegratingFactor.html#:%7E:text=An%20integrating%20factor%20is%20a,(1)) and is
$$f(x)=e^x\int e^{-x}(1-2x)g(x)\mathrm{d}x=e^x\left(\int e^{-x}g(x)\mathrm{d}x-2\int xe^{-x}g(x)\mathrm{d}x\right)$$
I suppose you're going to have to get creative from here on out, but this is probably a good start. Not sure how useful this is, but I hope it helped a little!

Comment: In the second step, you should not derive $g (x)$ from the right side of the equality

Comment: Please explain? Sorry if I made an error

Comment: in this equality, $$f'(x)=g(x)+f(x)-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\int_{0}^{2x}t\cdot g\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)\mathrm{d}t$$  it is the first in the equality of the right, it should also be derived to g (x), consequently the procedure would be wrong from the start or I was wrong?

Comment: No, the $t$ factor changes things significantly. You need to integrate by parts and account for the chain rule.